# Unknown column "something" in 'where clause'

Tags: c#

My problem is always in throw. please help me to find the problem. thanks!

```
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqladdress);

cnn.Open();

try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where StudentID ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Name='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    int count = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
    }
    else if (count > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Access Denied");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong student ID and Password");
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: What DavidG said. Also, .NET specific: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: You need a space between the single quote and the word 'and'

Comment: Voted to close it as typo error

Comment: Is it possible that in `textBox1` you entered the value `'; select * from table where Something=5; --` ?

Comment: @w0lf Or even better: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

This must be a typo or something simple which is hard to tell without knowing the exact error message.

To avoid such errors i would recommend you to use parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where StudentID = @StudentID and Name= @Name";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
```